# c++ boost thread_group with asycron returns

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I´m trying to write a function that handles both input arguments and return values from a thread in a thread group.

My example class:

```
  // includes...
class MyClass(int id)
  {
  thread_id = id;
  i = id* 5; 
  b = false;
 }

void resetCounter(int j){
  i = j * 5;
 }
int getId(){
 return id;
}
bool getBool(){
  return b;
 }

void DoWork(){
  while( i > 0 ){
     boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(i));
      i--;
  }
  b = true;  // DoWork will in the real code be able to return false!
  }
  private:
  bool b;
  int i;
  int thread_id
 };

  boost::threadgroup threads;
```

Exemple code:

```
  bool exist = false;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  // first check if thread id exist (possible)? 
  // If so don´t create a new thread but reset the counter!
  if(exist){
   // in current thread call reset "i" (w.resetCounter(i))
   }else{
    MyClass m(i);
    boost::function<void()> thread_func = boost::bind(&MyClass::DoWork, &m);
    threads.create_thread(thread_func);
   }
 }
```

I want to iterate through the threads and be able to check if DoWork returned true.

How do I implement this?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I want to implement this pseudo-code but not sure how to.Actually there is multiple questions.

Comment: The most important is how I´ll make a thread when finished wait 1 second for other threads to finish. Then collect a group of "thread-ID:s" that was finished within that second: but only if "DoWork" returned true.

Comment: Also I want to be able, given a special "thread-ID" (which could be a string btw, and the requested "thread-ID" will be passed to this function by the parameter list), to check if the thread-id is running. If the thread is still running then I want to reset its counter. Otherwise... If it is requested but not running then it should be created.

Comment: this is quite meaningless: the thread might be running in the moment you're checking it, but finish next moment.

Comment: That is okey. Unless that would create some errors: the thing is that a thread could end in one sec up to 20 min. Basically they´re supposed to be listeners. So it is not random but you don´t know when they´ll return success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, with `thread_group` you can't iterate over the thread objects. So if this's what you want, consider storing thread objects in some other container.

Besides, you can't portably wait until one thread finishes, but if you don't mind using Windows-specific API, you can do this with `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

However, I would recommend you re-designing your application, to avoid such tricks.

Comment: I discovered another way to achieve what I need by making a re-design of my application and thus accept this as the final answer.